# Create a TypeScript class with just one computed property

Tags: json, typescript

Does it make sense to create a class with just one computed property as key so I can handle the JSON response?

I have the following problem, I want to create a blog post. There are 3 different options to create one.

- A) Blog Post EN
- B) Blog Post GER
- C) Blog Post FR

Depending on the blog post there should be different templates.

Now I want to have a master view where I can edit all the posts in a handy way.

The JSON for that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "B1": {
      "A": {
        "Headline": "Hello World",
        "Text": "This is a hello world text"
      },
      "B": {
        "Headline": "Hallo Welt",
        "Text": "Ein Hallo Welt Text"
      },
      "C": {
        "Headline": "Bonjour Monde",
        "Text": "Le monde est à toi."
      }
    }
  }
]
```

B1 is the unique blog post identifier. A,B,C should be seen as the template keys. If "A" then it means we want to use template A.

Now for the actual question, I want to use TypeScript and it's features.

Does the class BlogPostIdObject makes sense? I only create it to have an easy way to parse the incoming JSON into a object with a specific shape.

```
export class RootObject {
  blogposts: BlogPostIdObject[]
}

export class BlogPostIdObject {
  [templateIdObject: string]: TemplateIdObject
}

export class TemplateIdObject {
  Headline: string;
  Text: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I will assign your JSON-style object literal to a constant called `json`:

```
const json = [
  {
    "B1": {
      "A": {
        "Headline": "Hello World",
        "Text": "This is a hello world text"
      },
      "B": {
        "Headline": "Hallo Welt",
        "Text": "Ein Hallo Welt Text"
      },
      "C": {
        "Headline": "Bonjour Monde",
        "Text": "Le monde est à toi."
      }
    }
  }
];
```

There are a few problems with your type definitions.  First, assuming you want to just assign a JSON-style object to a variable of type `RootObject`, you shouldn't use `class`.  You create an instance of a class by calling its constructor, like `new RootObject()`; you can't just assign/cast an object literal to it.  TypeScript will let you do that, but you will likely probably run into problems at runtime.  Instead, use either `interface` or `type`, which will accept object literals.  So let's switch to `interface`:

```
export interface RootObject {
  blogposts: BlogPostIdObject[]
}

export interface BlogPostIdObject {
  [templateIdObject: string]: TemplateIdObject
}

export interface TemplateIdObject {
  Headline: string;
  Text: string;
}
```

Okay, let's try it!

```
const interpretedJson: RootObject = json; // error!
```

Uh oh, it's complaining that `json` doesn't contain a property named `blogposts`.  And it doesn't.  Really, you want `RootObject` just to *be* an array of `BlogPostIdObject[]`, not to *have* an array:

```
// note, changed to type alias instead of interface
export type RootObject = BlogPostIdObject[];

export interface BlogPostIdObject {
  [templateIdObject: string]: TemplateIdObject
}

export interface TemplateIdObject {
  Headline: string;
  Text: string;
}
```

Let's try again!

```
const interpretedJson: RootObject = json; // error!
```

Now it's complaining that `json[0].B1` doesn't match `TemplateIdObject`.  And it doesn't, because a `TemplateIdObject` doesn't actually have the template ids at all; it just has the `Headline` and `Text` properties.  Really, you want `TemplateIdObject` to have properties whose keys are some strings, and whose values have `Headline` and `Text` properties.  Let's fix it by breaking apart `TemplateIdObject` into the keys and the values (which I'll call `TemplateValuesObject`):

```
export type RootObject = BlogPostIdObject[];

export interface BlogPostIdObject {
  [blogIdKey: string]: TemplateIdObject
}

export interface TemplateIdObject {
  [templateIdKey: string]: TemplateValuesObject
}

export interface TemplateValuesObject {
  Headline: string;
  Text: string;
}

const interpretedJson: RootObject = json; // okay
```

So, now it works.  Hooray, we're all done, right?

---

Well, I don't know.  That definition isn't very restrictive.

It will let you have blog posts with many ids, like `[{"B1": {...}, "B2": {...}, ...}]`, or zero ids, like `[{}]`.  Is that okay?  If not, maybe the JSON structure itself isn't great, because JSON objects are not designed to hold a single property of unknown name. You should think about changing the JSON to look more like `[{"blogId":"B1", "templates":{"A"...}}]` so that each blog post in the array has exactly one `blogId` and one set of `templates`.

It will let you have templates with many ids, like `[{"B1":{"A": {...}, "B": {...}, "C": {...}, "D": {...}, ...}}]` or no ids, like `[{"B1": {}}]`. Is that okay?  If not, should they be exactly `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"`?  If so, you can specify that by changing `TemplateIdObject` to have those exact keys.

So it's up to you if you're done or you need more revision to your type definitions or possibly the JSON structure itself.  Hope that helps; good luck!